# Group inserted array with a unique key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am using https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya to create multiple form inputs like this:

```
create_order_shirt_shoulder[0] // name of the form
create_order_shirt_chest[0] // name of the form
```

And I can duplicate this form container which will result to:

```
create_order_shirt_shoulder[1] // name of the form
create_order_shirt_shoulder[2] // name of the form
...
```

My insert code looks like

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $val)
{
    if (is_array($val)) {
        foreach ($val as $value)
        {
            $value = strip_tags($value);

            $items = array(
                'order_item_reference' => $reference,
                'order_item_key' => $key,
                'order_item_value' => $value,
                'order_item_group' => " " // group id
            );

            $this->db->insert('user_orders_items', $items);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to group each group array with a unique key, lets say all array that belongs to [0] to have "#1" in my `order_item_group` column

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain more what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: *I have a form input like this `create_order_shirt_shoulder[0]`* -- I may be mistaken but it doesn't look like a *form input*.

Comment: Is don't understand your question. Can you elaborate more in depth?

Comment: Where's `$reference` declared?

Comment: @CodeGodie @Viral ... I have edited my question, I am generating `$reference` as a unique random key for each order.

Comment: @Shina Can you `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to show the structure of the data?

Comment: @phpchap see http://jsbin.com/hafona/1/edit?js,output

Comment: You shouldn't be using `$_REQUEST` in a codeigniter project.  There are dedicated methods for collecting posted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the key from the sub-array to group all related items from the sub-arrays together?

For example:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $val)
{
    if (is_array($val)) {
        foreach ($val as $groupId => $value)
        {
            $value = strip_tags($value);

            $items = array(
                'order_item_reference' => $reference,
                'order_item_key' => $key,
                'order_item_value' => $value,
                'order_item_group' => $groupId // group id
            );

            $this->db->insert('user_orders_items', $items);
        }
    }
}
```